# How to show arbitrary project in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have very custom project (including Matlab and other languages, including java maven projects soemewhere deep below) under `Git` control and would like to use IntelliJ as editor and version control UI. I have created "empty" project and fed root directory to wizard.

Now I see only top-level files in `Project` pane with no subdirectories shown.

Is it possible to show everything?

Comment: Are you using `New...` or `Open...` ?

Comment: `New`, which resulted in creating `.idea` subdirectory, which I added to `gitignore`.

Comment: Have you tried to run "Import project" from welcome screen, select your project root and choose "Create project  from existing sources"?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a module for the files to be visible:

Select `File > Project Structure > Modules`

Use the `+` symbol and select `Import Module`

Navigate to the root you wish to view and then `OK`

Select `Create module from existing sources` then `Next`

Next you will see a screen telling you source files have been found and their associated paths, simply select `Next`

Lastly you will see a screen listing any frameworks which were found, select `Finish`

You will now have your project with subdirectories visible.

**EDIT**

If you wish to add files which are read only and not intended to be built alongside your source code then:

1. Go to `Project Structure`
2. Go to the `Modules` menu item and select your new module
3. Find the `Mark as` menu and deselect all items

[More info here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-projects.html#folder-categories)

Intellij will now ignore these files when compiling etc

You could also investigate adding different [content roots](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-projects.html#adding_content_root)

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It finds Java maven projects deep inside, which I don't need (at least, don't need ONLY this). I need IntelliJ just display all files and directories, existing. Is it possible?

Comment: Updated, let me know if this helps

Comment: Did this help @Dims